# Placeholder HTML element?

Tags: html

Is there any HTML element that I can use to wrap other elements to use as a placeholder? For example,

```
<ul>
    <placeholder id="list-placeholder">
        <li>item 1</li>
        <li>item 2</li>
    </placeholder>
    <li>last item</li>
</ul>
```

Then I'd be able to access `#list-placeholder` via JavaScript and append children to it.

- I don't think I can use `<div>` because divs aren't valid in all contexts (such as a list); furthermore, they may be inadvertently styled (I want my placeholder to be invisible).
- Browsers don't render the contents of `<template>` whereas I *do* want to render what's inside my placeholder
- Likewise, `<script>` tags with a custom `type` don't render their contents either

Answer (score 2):

No, in HTML, there is no general wrapper element—which is what this is really about. What comes closest is `ins` and `del` elements, which can wrap both inline and block elements and have transparent content model. But even they are not allowed e.g. as a child of a `ul` element.

Instead of trying to use a wrapper e.g. for some `li` elements in order to apped children to it, set an `id` attribute on the last of the `li` elements in question and insert siblings after it. This is more natural in terms of DOM, since then all the `li` elements will be children of `ul`, instead of being partly children, partly grandchildren.

Comment: The placeholder would be generated via a framework, which is why I need a general-purpose solution. I don't think I can identify the last element before the closing tag reliably, particularly if its a text node. Anyway, thanks for the info.

Answer (score 0):

According to W3, only a `<li>` can be a child of a `<ul>`, therefore, the answer to your question is no.  There is not a valid way to wrap two `<li>`s that are children of a `<ul>`.

If you have to, you could use a `<span>`.  I have created an example, while not valid, this runs correctly in all modern browsers.

Example snippet and some proof below:

```js
function showList(){
  
  document.getElementById('list-placeholder').style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById('showList').style.display = "none";
  }
```

```html
<ul>
    <span id="list-placeholder" style="display:none;">
        <li>item 1</li>
        <li>item 2</li>
    </span>
    <li>last item</li>
</ul>

<input type="button" value="Show more list items!" onclick="showList()"/>
```

If you don't HAVE TO use a wrapper, you can and should use the following VALID code:

```js
function showList(){
  
  var hidden = document.getElementsByClassName('hidden')
  
  for (i=0; i<hidden.length; i++){
    
    hidden[i].style.display = "list-item";
    
    }
  document.getElementById('showList').style.display = "none";
}
```

```css
.hidden
{
  display:none;
  }
```

```html
<ul>
    
        <li class="hidden">item 1</li>
        <li class="hidden">item 2</li>
    
    <li>last item</li>
</ul>

<input type="button" value="Show more list items!" id="showList" onclick="showList()"/>
```

Use a class to select hidden items instead of a wrapper.  That's the correct syntax for your question.

Also, there are set `<script>` types, just like there are set `<input>` types (text, button, radio,  checkbox, range, etc.).  That is why you should specify the type, so the browser understands your code.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Factually incorrect. `li` is the only valid child of `ul` in html 5: http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/ul.html, note "0 or more li`. It does not validate via the W3c validator either. Also see: http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/li.html ; permitted parents "ul,ol and menu"

Comment: Not really, it is valid, but the OP is specifically looking for something to "wrap" the elememnts in, which adding a class does not really do. I don't believe that given the current HTML specs that there is a soluttion to the question as written.

Comment: No, the main reason, it is not valid. Additionaly it is often frowned upon to put a block\flow element inside an inline\phrasing element. The `a` tag is the exception to the rule.

Comment: True, but my answer will hopefully be a alternative to the quesion, since there is no "correct" way to do it.