# a HTML element that acts only as a placeholder

Tags: html, css

I am looking for a standard HTML element that would be [void](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Void_element) and would act only as a placeholder. It would be like `<img>` without the image. This tag could then be handled by simple CSS (or Javascript).

In my case, the custom element would be handled in the CSS like this:

```
.validated::after
{
  content: "OK";
  float: right;
}
```

You could imagine a empty `<div />`, that doesn't need to be written in two parts `<div></div>` and which would be empty. It could then be referred through an id, class or as a child element. Unlike `<div>`, I would like to be able to access it from a `<p>` and `<li>`.

The related question for placeholder doesn't solve my question: [Placeholder HTML element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26706500/placeholder-html-element)

I guess I could create my own element, but I was wondering if there were something standard in HTML for such purpose, or a usual trick used in that situation.

Comment: In what way does img have a line break?

Comment: You are right. I was taking <br> as an example before. It slept through my review.

Comment: No, there is no such element. An empty `<div>` is probably what you're after.

Comment: So why not use img, apart from the fact it would semantically rather odd of course.

Comment: cuz img does not have ::after that's why

Comment: I am still unclear as to what your aim is.  Also, I think float is valid only for div and img.

Comment: So is a span what you need? Perhaps you could list all the properties this element must have.

Answer (score 0):

```css
base::after {
  content: "text"
}
```

```html
<base>
```